# SQL query taking a ridiculous amount of time in fetching result set

Tags: sql, db2

I've been working on optimizing a number of SQL queries for a landing page in which the queries are pieced together based on user selections and fired off to a DB2 database. Everything was running pretty well, with many queries getting close to or under one second. As a performance test, we recently loaded up the test database with a truckload of data. One table was multiplied by about 20x, going from 40k or so records to 750k records. We were looking to get a rough simulation of the amount of data that would be present in a year or so. Some queries have been tweaked since, but one group in particular was hit ridiculously hard, which is the table with 750k records. The query itself has a number of joins, but I've found that cutting it down to select/filter on the single table still takes 30+ seconds. Sometimes the query itself takes that long, and sometimes the query runs in a few seconds, and then fetching rows counts upward at a ridiculously slow pace for 20+ seconds.

The query itself selects about a dozen columns from the table and filters on several criteria. The only way it's remotely fast is to cut it all way down and severely narrow the filter criteria to either greatly simplify filtering or drastically reduce the number of rows. It'll execute in a couple of seconds that way, but layering on any degree of complexity will delay execution like mad. The explain plan is no help. It shows a cost far, FAR lower than the runtime would suggest, as in well under 100k. With those numbers, you'd expect it to run in well under 2 seconds.

Indexes are in place, but I'm starting to wonder if perhaps a bad index is really choking it. To get an idea of the query structure...

```
SELECT 
--12 or so fields
FROM
TABLE A
--A few joins
WHERE
A.FIELD1 is not null
AND a.FIELD2 IN (:param) --max 2 values here
AND (a.FIELD3 BETWEEN :date1 AND date2
(OR A.FIELD3 < :date3 AND A.FIELD4 IN ('ONE','TWO')))
```

I've already tinkered and removed bits from the OR clause, which only helped on the very simple queries. Otherwise the runtime is still way too long to make a difference. Runstats/distributed statistics are accurate. The table just got reorged, with no help. I'm hoping someone might have a few pointers here.

UPDATE: Distributed statistics were run. SYSIBM.SYSCOLDIST and SYSCAT.COLDIST both show current data for TABLE A. The queries are still running horridly and taking forever to fetch the results. There may be a difference for the better, but it's not nearly enough to be significant. It's worth noting that adjusting the filter to return a small result set executes very quickly. Changing the filters to return a larger one takes forever to fetch the rows. A few simple inner joins don't seem to wreck the runtime, but anything remotely large or complex blows it out completely. This is the only table exhibiting this behavior. There are others with 2.7 million rows that run faster than this.

Aaaand I think I found the problem. Turns out that the dataload put those dates into the range of a week, so even touching that range will blow the dataset up to several hundred thousand rows. Criminy. Time for a script to grab dates in that range and update the rows with a better distribution across the space of a year...

Aaaand that wasn't entirely the problem. Setting that date range to a wide area before the data load brings up about 4.5k results, which is fine, but it still takes about 9 seconds, 3.5s spent fetching the result set.

Comment: If you want people to help you solve this problem, you need to expound upon `--A few joins`. These joins will have a significant impact on your performance.

Comment: Removing the joins doesn't make the query faster, at least not to any relevant degree. It can still take 30+ seconds with only the single table and filter conditions. With the joins...eesh, over a minute. However, the root of the problem is definitely in TABLE A.

Comment: Which member of the DB2 family are you using? DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS?

Comment: I'm using DB2 for LUW.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it as a UNION? You can use UNION ALL if you want any duplicates to show.

```
SELECT --12 or so fields
FROM TABLE A
--A few joins
WHERE A.FIELD1 is not null
AND a.FIELD2 IN (:param) --max 2 values here
AND a.FIELD3 BETWEEN :date1 AND date2
UNION
SELECT --12 or so fields
FROM TABLE A
--A few joins
WHERE A.FIELD1 is not null
AND a.FIELD2 IN (:param) --max 2 values here
AND A.FIELD3 < :date3 
AND A.FIELD4 IN ('ONE','TWO')
```

If this isn't any faster can you post you EXPLAIN plan?

Answer (score 0):

Outdated statistics are often the reason for slow queries, especially when missing indexes aren't the problem.

The explain plan with the "low" costs also supports this.

And the fact that you just inserted a huge amount of data makes this a very plausible cause.

Comment: Well I'll be. Looks like RUNSTATS have been done after the data load, but not with any distribution statistics, which I thought had been done. I'll get that data collected and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @user1017413: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I'll know soon as I'm waiting on the DBAs. The date range was definitely part of it, but I think it was also an OR clause that wasn't a problem prior to the dataload along with a suboptimal index.